# How to run multiple sidekiq workers in parallel in Rails development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

When using my rails application in development mode, if I call a worker while inside of another, the called one does not run until the one that called it is completed. For example, if `Worker1` calls `Worker2`, `Worker2` will just says that it's "running" but it actually does not execute any code until `Worker` is complete. In production, it seems like it's the opposite - it runs when you call it and that's what I'm looking to get in development.

How do I accomplish this in development mode? Seems a little tough to be able to test the same scenario if only one sidekiq worker runs at a time in development mode.

My `config/sidekiq.yml` file looks like this:

```
development:  
  :concurrency: 50
```

but only one job still runs at a time. Not quite sure why this is happening and limiting me.

Answer (score 0):

See the settings in config/environment/production.rb. You need to turn on eager loading to get concurrency. In return you will lose code reloading.

Comment: This is only happening in development mode though. In production, workers run in parallel with no problem -- just trying to do the same in dev. Is code reloading the ability to modify code without having to restart the server?

Comment: Yes it only happens in development because the settings in config/environment/development.rb are different from production.